# Javascript will not update or display the system time< how come?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my javascript code, I checked it in Chrome and its not giving me an error

```
window.onload = function() {

    var timeClock = function (){

        setTimeout("timeClock()", 1000);  

        var timeObj = new Date();

        var currTime = timeObj.getHours(); + " : " + timeObj.getMinutes(); + " : " + timeObj.getSeconds();

        document.getElementById("#clock-container").innerHTML = "asd";

    }
}
```

I am trying to update this div with the current system time

```
<div id="clock-container"></div>
```

Comment: Are you seeing "asd"?

Comment: why are you setting inner html as asd?

Comment: There is some typos: `var currTime = timeObj.getHours();` <- that semicolon shouldn't be there, same for minutes part. Also, *setTimeout* code is run in global context, but *timeClock* is declared inside function expression, so out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple logic and other mistakes.

1. You are attempting to register the callback, but your `setTimeout` is in the callback itself. Move `setTimeout("timeClock()", 1000);` outside the callback.
2. Presumably you also want to replace `setTimeout` with `setInterval` to have the clock continuously update, and also avoid having to call `setTimeout` in the callback.
3. There's also no reason to use a string to call `timeClock`, so use `setInterval(timeClock, 1000);` instead and avoid the evil that is code evaluation.
4. `document.getElementById("#clock-container")` should be `document.getElementById("clock-container")`.
5. Your `currTime` expression has several `;` where they don't belong, fix those and you can use this variable instead of your string.
6. You can also call `timeClock` immediately after load, to avoid waiting for the first interval.

### Working Example:

```js
window.onload = function() {

    var timeClock = function (){

        var timeObj = new Date();

        var currTime = timeObj.getHours() + " : " + timeObj.getMinutes() + " : " + timeObj.getSeconds();

        document.getElementById("clock-container").innerHTML = currTime;

    }

    setInterval(timeClock, 1000);
    timeClock();
}
```

```html
<div id="clock-container"></div>
```

Comment: With clocks, I use *setTimeout* then set the delay to just after the next full second. *setInterval* slowly drifts, so from time to time it will skip a second.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you're trying to do but The script should be

```js
window.onload = function() {

var timeClock = function (){


    var timeObj = new Date();
    var currTime = timeObj.getHours() + " : " + timeObj.getMinutes() + " : " + timeObj.getSeconds();

    document.getElementById("clock-container").innerHTML = currTime;


    setTimeout(timeClock, 1000);  

}

timeClock();  
}
```